# How to Group Products by Manufacturer or Supplier

Tags: magento2, product, product-grid

I am beginning to load products in my store. I would like to organize the products by manufacturer. There is a column in the product grid for "country of origin", but I don't see any for manufacturer or supplier. Can I add a column to the grid through Magento, or must it be done through phpMyAdmin? Or, maybe it can't or shouldn't be done at all??

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a custom attribute? Then you can create a custom attribute set for those products and add the "Manufacturer" attribute to your layered nav?

Comment: I went to the Stores|Attributes|Products menu and added an attribute for "Brands". Then, I went back to the Catalog|Inventory|Products page to add new product to the catalog. I don't see the "brand" attribute in the grid, and I cannot select it in the dropdown systems columns menu. There are 33 attributes in this dropdown menu and I would like to add or edit one attribute.

Comment: Have you added it to the default attribute set?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't ask what version you are using? I'm more familiar with Mage 2, but surely it should work for both. Go to Stores>Product Attribute. You should be able to create the attribute. Then create an attribute set and add it to that set. This way you can apply all the attributes that are relevant to your specific products.

Comment: I managed to find and add it. I am working with Mage 2. Now I begin to build a csv file to upload my products. I am trying to make sense of the SKU numbers used in the Luma sample data. Thanks for helping me get oriented with the product attributes!